# Simple Text effects like this images

Tags: text, photoshop-effects, illustrator-effects

I am a beginner.  I want to create text effects similar to this images.

What i have to do?  Which tool can i use?

If anyone have a link to tutorial, please give me.

[image: Triaster]
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Your question is very broad. In Photoshop such effects are part of the Layer Styles, such as Bevel and Emboss, Drop Shadow, and Stroke. Use google to find tutorials.  This isn't a tutorial request website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In photoshop: Create a text layer. Add layer style by clicking the fx button in the layers panel. For your left example, choose "Bevel and emboss" - play around with settings in the Layer Style panel until you are satisfied. Then tick the "Drop shadow" in the layer style panel to add a shadow. Change settings like opacity, distance, spread and size.

For your right example you can use "Stroke" instead of "Bevel and emboss" as layer effect.

See more at: https://design.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-use-drop-shadows-in-photoshop--psd-16652

Answer (score 1):

For applying shadow effect to text you need to add shadow in text

follow this steps :-

go to **Add a Layer Style -> Drop shadow**

add shadow as per below

[image]

and the result is as below

[image]